# How to make a sequence in google sheets which has increments in regular intervals

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a sequence in **google sheets** where i have to make a sequence of this sort like if the sequence starts at 5000, it should be 5000 for the next 12 rows and then it should increment to 5500 and then it should go on for another 12 rows to be 5500. So basically it should increment by 10% after 12 rows and continue to do this.

Comment: So should the next 12 rows be 6000 (+ 10% of 5000) or 6050 (+10% of 5500) ?

Comment: The next 12 rows should be (+10% of 5500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(quotient(sequence(Blocklength*Blocks,1,0),Blocklength),
{sequence(Blocks,1,0),Start*(1+Increment)^(sequence(Blocks,1,0))},2))
```

[image]

*Comment*

You don't actually need the vlookup, could go straight to the calculation, but with a power calculation in every row this might be slower:

```
=ArrayFormula(Start*(1+Increment)^quotient(sequence(Blocklength*Blocks,1,0),Blocklength))
```

Comment: This seems to be working but can you explain it a bit. I am new to using sheets.

Comment: I'm using the compound interest formula Principal*(1+Interest)^period to generate 5000, 5500, 6050...etc then generating numbers 0 to 119 using sequence, then using Quotient to convert those to 12 zeroes followed by 12 1's then 12 2's and finally looking those up in the compound interest values to get the results you wanted. As noted, I could have just gone straight to compound interest: Principal*(1+Interest)^period, where period is  12 zeroes followed by 12 1's then 12 2's as before.

Comment: I am a beginner in excel, so will try and figure this out. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this a bit tricky, maybe others have smoother answers. But one way is to use `FV()` function for a compound interest. With a combination of `SEQUENCE()` you can get the cumulative increase:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(FV(D3,SEQUENCE(D4),0,-(D1/(D3+1)))&"|",D2),"|",1)))
```

Or, without the `FV()` function, but with math and same concept:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(D1*(1+D3)^SEQUENCE(D4,1,0)&"|",D2),"|",1)))
```

---

**Note:** For reading purposes I set blocksize to **2 rows** only.

Comment: Yes I found it tricky as well but well done.

Comment: Of course, well spotted.

Comment: Could you please explain this formula a bit. I want to understand how is it working and why is it working

Comment: @SahaajSinghChawla; In both options we created an array-formula which will return multiple answers due to the presence of `SEQUENCE()`. Each iteration in the latter will result in a value we copy a given amount using `REPT()`. It's a simple matter of `SPLIT()` and `FLATTEN()` after that. Why the theory of compound interest works is a matter of math and don't need explaination but a google search =)

Comment: I think that cleared out something for me and I will google it to get a better understanding of it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try, with B1=5000, B2=10%, B3=24 periods (288 values=24*12)

```
=arrayformula(sort(flatten(sequence(12,1,B1,0)*(1+B2)^(sequence(1,B3,0,1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is working too but it isnt dynamic in nature, like i have a duration till which it should be growing. but this will only work for a fixed 36 cells

Comment: ok, i will extend the function